# Were both of Jodie's parents linked to Entities?

Tags: video-games, beyond-two-souls

In the video game *Beyond: Two Souls*, there's some mention of Jodie's parents both having psychic/supernatural mental abilities.  In one scene, we see her mother move a cup using these abilities.  But I didn't see the source or method of these powers explained.  There's an implication there that both her parents are linked to entities like Jodie is, but that seems incredibly unlikely given the late-game reveal of where Aiden came from.

Were Jodie's parent's linked to entities, or did they have a different type of special ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spoilers**

I think they were just special abilities, because as you said: the ending reveal surely explains the uniqueness of Jodie's entity. Although, in the Navajo act, after the funeral (assuming you perform the ritual correctly), Jodie goes up into a cave and sees a very similar cave drawing showing that linked entities surely have existed before Jodie and Aiden, lending some *possibility* of the parents having such a linked entity.

That being said, I still find it hard to see both parents having the same abilities given the following:

1. Aiden's unique existence
2. Norah being successfully 'put under' (her entity not saving her)
3. Norah's entity not killing her (as she expresses her will to have just died)
4. Aiden not being able to see Norah's entity in the 'Norah' act. Remember Jodie/Aiden can see other entities of all sorts in every other act (Monsters, dead family members, etc.), so surely he/she would be able to see another linked entity?
5. The DPA seems to have not heard of such a case as Jodie's (being linked to an entity), as Dawkins is very curious in their first encounter.
6. When Cole tells Jodie about Norah, he makes no statement of the sort: Norah had an entity like Aiden.

**EDIT**

After my third playthrough, my answer remains the same.